# Spring Data MongoDB com.mongodb.MongoWaitQueueFullException

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to insert data into MongoDB in multiple threads using Spring Data MongoDB framework. But unfortunately I get following error:

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoWaitQueueFullException: Too many threads are already waiting for a connection. Max number of threads (maxWaitQueueSize) of 50 has been exceeded.
at com.mongodb.PooledConnectionProvider.get(PooledConnectionProvider.java:70)
at com.mongodb.DefaultServer.getConnection(DefaultServer.java:60)
at com.mongodb.BaseCluster$WrappedServer.getConnection(BaseCluster.java:216)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector$MyPort.getConnection(DBTCPConnector.java:503)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector$MyPort.get(DBTCPConnector.java:451)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:286)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:271)
at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.find(DBCollectionImpl.java:84)
at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.find(DBCollectionImpl.java:66)
at com.mongodb.DBCursor._check(DBCursor.java:458)
at com.mongodb.DBCursor._hasNext(DBCursor.java:546)
at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:571)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1782)
... 22 more
```

I'm using following configuration for Spring:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties"/>

<mongo:mongo host="${mongo.db.host}" port="${mongo.db.port}"/>
<mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" dbname="${mongo.db.name}"/>

<mongo:repositories base-package="com.test.app.mongodb.dao"/>
<mongo:template db-factory-ref="mongoDbFactory" converter-ref="mappingConverter" write-concern="ACKNOWLEDGED"/>
<mongo:mapping-converter id="mappingConverter" db-factory-ref="mongoDbFactory" type-mapper-ref="defaultMongoTypeMapper"
                         mapping-context-ref="mappingContext"/>

<bean id="defaultMongoTypeMapper" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultMongoTypeMapper">
    <constructor-arg name="typeKey">
        <null/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="mappingContext" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext"/>
```

As I understood from documentation there are a few properties which are responsible for allowed connections number (default combination of them allow 50 connections per node). They could be configured with Spring: *connections-per-host* and *threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier*. I tried to use first one as shown below:

```
<mongo:mongo host="${mongo.db.host}" port="${mongo.db.port}">
    <mongo:options connections-per-host="100"/>
</mongo:mongo>
```

But result is the same. I still get that exception about 50 allowed connections.

I would be very grateful if somebody could explain what I did wrong. Has anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717726/how-to-configure-mongo-max-thread