# how to configure Mongo max thread?

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I have Mongo injected in to the spring.
Everything works well. But when I try to persist data using too many threads , I have such errors:

```
nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Too many threads are already waiting for a connection. Max number of threads (maxWaitQueueSize) of 50 has been exceeded.; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoWaitQueueFullException: Too many threads are already waiting for a connection. Max number of threads (maxWaitQueueSize) of 50 has been exceeded.] with root cause
com.mongodb.MongoWaitQueueFullException: Too many threads are already waiting for a connection. Max number of threads (maxWaitQueueSize) of 50 has been exceeded.
    at com.mongodb.PooledConnectionProvider.get(PooledConnectionProvider.java:70)
```

Where can I increase this setting?

I have only this config:

```
<bean id="mongo" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
    <property name="host" value="X.X.X.X" />
    <property name="port" value="27017"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo" />
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="test" />
</bean>
```

And My Log Service in Spring:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class LogService {

    @Autowired  
    MongoOperations mongoOperations;  

    public void saveTransactionLog(Log l) {
        mongoOperations.save(l);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38930489/3380878

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <bean id="mongo" class="com.mongodb.Mongo">
      <constructor-arg name="addr" ref="address" />
      <constructor-arg name="options" ref="options" />
   </bean>

   <bean id="options" class="com.mongodb.MongoOptions">
      <property name="connectionsPerHost" value="${mongo.db.pool.size}"/>
      <property name="maxWaitTime" value="${mongo.db.pool.maxwait}"/>
   </bean>

   <bean id="address" class="com.mongodb.ServerAddress">
      <constructor-arg name="host" value="${mongo.db.host}" />
      <constructor-arg name="port" value="${mongo.db.port}" />
   </bean>

   <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
      <constructor-arg ref="mongo" />
      <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="${mongo.db.name}" />
   </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [xsd](http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.5.xsd), under `threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier` property, it states

> The multiplier for connectionsPerHost for # of threads that can block. Default is 5. If connectionsPerHost is 10, and threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier is 5, then 50 threads can block more than that and an exception will be thrown.

So I'm thinking you could do something like

```
<property name="threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier" value="xx" />
```

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier' of bean class

Answer (score 0):

add method how to put  property name="connectionsPerHost" in java config

```
public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
    return new MongoClient("127.0.0.1",MongoClientOptions.builder()
                                                         .connectionsPerHost(250)
                                                         .build());
```